# How to set Kivy TextInput background color depending on focus

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy, textinput

Kivy has the properties `background_active` and `background_normal` for setting a `TextInput` widget's background when it is in focus and when it is not in focus, respectively. However, this sets a background image, and not an `rgba` color. There is a `background_color` property, but this sets the `TextInput`'s background color regardless of whether or not it is in focus.

How can I change an `TextInput`'s background color depending on whether or not it is focused?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a new **TextInput** in the KV file

```
<MyTextInput@TextInput>:
    background_color: (1,0,0,1) if self.focus else (0,0,1,1)
```

This will bind the *focus* attribute so the color will change according to the focus...